# Bash shell filtering [Updated sample data]

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix

I have a csv with the following columns:

*status_id,user_id,created_at,screen_name,text,source,reply_to_status_id,reply_to_user_id,reply_to
_screen_name,is_quote,is_retweet,favourites_count,retweet_count,country_code,place_full_name,
place_type,followers_count,friends_count,account_lang,account_created_at,verified,lang*

```
status_id   user_id created_at  screen_name text    source  reply_to_status_id  reply_to_user_id    reply_to_screen_name    is_quote    is_retweet  favourites_count    retweet_count   country_code    place_full_name place_type  followers_count friends_count   account_lang    account_created_at  verified    lang
1.23789E+18 3520752864  2020-03-12T00:00:00Z    Tokyo_gov   Watch this newly released video featuring a message from Tokyo's Governor Koike on #COVID19 below #Coronavirus  TweetDeck               FALSE   FALSE   3   37              118670  16      2015-09-11T00:05:21Z    TRUE    en
1.23789E+18 1056850669  2020-03-12T00:00:00Z    airnewsalerts   60 positive cases of #Covid19 in India  says Health Ministry    TweetDeck               FALSE   FALSE   605 12              2236114 13      2013-01-03T04:15:45Z    TRUE    en
1.23789E+18 794162328   2020-03-12T00:00:00Z    StatesideRadio  UM medical historian @HowardMarkel says he doesn't feel fearful about #COVID19. But he does think there's plenty to learn about how decisions are made in outbreaks.    TweetDeck               FALSE   FALSE   662 0               3786    412     2012-08-31T16:08:32Z    FALSE   en
1.23789E+18 38489678    2020-03-12T00:00:00Z    JAMA_current    This JAMA Insights article reviews care for the most severely ill patients with #coronavirus disease 2019 (#COVID19)  including standards of management of #ARDS  preventing #SARSCoV2 spread in health care settings  and surge preparation    Sprinklr                FALSE   FALSE   1249    135             335352  805     2009-05-07T18:45:39Z    TRUE    en
1.23789E+18 8.24565E+17 2020-03-12T00:00:00Z    ViralTabNews    He beat the #coronavirus at age of101   #Covid19    TweetDeck               FALSE   FALSE   19  0               86  529     2017-01-26T10:31:04Z    FALSE   en
1.23789E+18 20178548    2020-03-12T00:00:00Z    DentonRC    .@UNTnews professors were told Wednesday to consider ways to bring their courses online.  Spokespeople for other area schools said Wednesday that they're closely watching the spread of #COVID19 but had not made a decision to suspend classes    Twitter Web App             FALSE   FALSE   564 5               13391   530     2009-02-05T19:37:33Z    TRUE    en
```

This is the question I'm trying to answer:

**Filter all the tweets with lang = ‘en’ which contain the term ‘Corona’ or ‘Covid’.
Export the tweets to a new file named “covid19Final.csv”. Ensure that you restrict the
tweets only to verified users who have retweeted at least 20 times. Ensure that the file
“covid19Final.csv” contains the column names as well.**

```
1:
    sort -k 2 -t , -n processed-covid-data.csv >> sorted_process_covind.csv

2:
    awk -F ',' '{ OFS=","; if ($2 == prev) {offset++} else offset=1; print 
    (offset","$2","$5","$22); prev=$2}' sorted_process_covind.csv | awk '$1>=20' 
    > again_valid_tweets.csv
3:

    awk -F ',' '$4 =="en" { print $3} ' again_valid_tweets.csv | grep -e "Covid" 
    -e "Corona" >covid19Final.csv
```

My 3rd line is returning an empty CSV. Help!

Comment: What is in `again_valid_tweets.csv`? What comes out of the (second) awk process and goes into the grep?

Comment: What is the output of `awk -F ',' '$4 =="en" { print $0} ' again_valid_tweets.csv | grep -e "Covid" -e "Corona" >covid19Final.csv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will, you need to provide some sample data what constitutes `verified` and how the `retweet_count` count is formatted so that can be verified. That said, `awk` is the tool for the job and you can do what you need with two-rules (or two conditions). You do not want to create a pipeline spawning unnecessary processes to reprocess data that you can handle in `awk` alone.

The first rule (or condition) simply outputs the header row to the new file `covid19Final.csv` (e.g. `FNR==1`).

The second rule (or set of conditions) checks if `lang` (`$NF`) is `"en"` and `verified` (`$(NF-1)`) is `"true"` (**adjust for whatever** `verified` **actually contains**), whether `retweet_count` (`$13`) is greater than or equal to `20` and finally if the records contains `"Corona"` or `"Covid"`, output the record to the new file.

There are two ways to approach this. The first simply matches the record and then uses the shell to redirect to the new file (preferred):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1 || ($NF=="en" && $(NF-1)=="true" && $13>=20 && $0~/Corona|Covid/)' input_file.csv > covid19Final.csv
```

(essentially if the 1st row or if your match all the conditions, rely on the default `print` to output the records read from `input_file.csv` and simply redirecting the results to the new file `covid19Final.csv`.

The second approach (effectively equivalent) is to write the two rules using each the first row condition, or matched criteria condition to redirect output to your new file within the rules themselves, e.g.

```
awk -F, '
    FNR==1 {
        print $0 > "covid19Final.csv"
    }
    $NF=="en" && $(NF-1)=="true" && $13>=20 && $0~/Corona|Covid/ {
        print $0 > "covid19Final.csv"
    }
' input_file.csv
```

The benefit here is it is easier to read.

Remember, you haven't posted what 'verified`contains, so if the indication for`verified`is something other than`true/false`, you need to adjust that test to match your data. The same goes for`retweet_count`.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't decide between the one-liner or split into rules -- so we did both.

Comment: David. Thank you so much for an excellent  detailed answer. 

When I run my code the first one that is I'm getting an empty CSV with only the headers. You asked me about verified which is a 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' and retweets are just numbers.  My input file is 4.1G called 'processed-covid-data.csv'.
I used your first code replacing NF with the column number and also the input file. Any idea what am I still doing wrong?

Comment: `awk -F, 'FNR==1 || ($22=="en" && $(21)=="TRUE" && $13>=20 && $5~/Corona|Covid/)' processed-covid-data.csv > covid19Final.csv`

Gives me a balnk csv with only the headers!

Comment: Okay I replaced '==' with '~' and it seemed to work. Can you explain why this happened? @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Glad it worked. Either should be fine. The difference is `==` checks string equality while `~` treats the contents as regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new user, and it seems I cannot comment. So, I post it here. 
I'm not sure if using ~ results in correct filtering:

$5~/Corona|Covid/ will filter for any word that contains any of these two words? For instance, Coronavirus or #Corona will also be included?

$22~"en" will include other words, for instance "enu"?

What is the method to exactly fitler for the word(s)? Similar to poster's case, I'm facing a situation that == does not work for me, too.